# Replacing lines of texts with another in different files in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script

I have a list of over 200 bind extensions files with exact subdomain information.

An example schema looks like this.

```
# /named_ext/db.mysite.com
subdomain                    A       200.201.202.203
```

I need to replace the entire line to a set of three different lines, likes this.

```
subdomain                    A       200.201.202.204
subdomain                    A       200.201.202.205
subdomain                    A       200.201.202.206
```

Any idea how to perform such replace under all `/named_ext/` files?

Comment: So would the search be for `*   A   200.201.202.203` -  in other words, any subdomain name, but specific A and IP address, or is the subdomain the same in each file?

Comment: the subdomain is the same in each file.

Comment: Are the ips to be added always increments of the original ip or are they constant?

Comment: they're constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following perl script `exchange_ips.pl` to exchange the ip either by three constant ips (function `exchange_const()`) or by three incremental ips (function `exchange_incr()`). Just add a comment (`#`) in front of the function call at the end of the script that you don't need.

**Note that one or more incremental ips will be incorrect if the original ip ends with `253` or higher.**

The script modifies all lines starting with `$domainname`. If the domain name doesn't matter or if your files only contain lines for just one/the same domain, then set `my $domainname = ".+";`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = <STDIN>;

my $domainname = "subdomain";
my $const_ip1 = "123.123.123.123";
my $const_ip2 = "124.124.124.124";
my $const_ip3 = "125.125.125.125";

my $pattern = qr/^($domainname\s+A\s+)([\d\.]+)/is;

sub exchange_const($) {
    my $dataref = shift;
    my $found = 0;
    foreach (@$dataref) {
        if ($_ =~ m/$pattern/) {
            unless ($found) {
                $found = 1;
                printf "%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n", $1, $const_ip1, $1, $const_ip2, $1, $const_ip3;
            }
        } else {
            print $_;
        }
    }
}

sub exchange_incr($) {
    my $dataref = shift;
    my $found = 0;
    foreach (@$dataref) {
        if ($_ =~ m/$pattern/) {
            unless ($found) {
                $found = 1;
                my $const = $1;
                my @iparr = split /\./, $2;
                for (1 .. 3) {
                    $iparr[3]++;
                    printf "%s%s\n", $const, join ".", @iparr;
                }
            }
        } else {
            print $_;
        }
    }
}

# exchange ip with constant ips
exchange_const(\@data);

# exchange ip with incremental ips
exchange_incr(\@data);
```

Call the script like this:

```
perl exchange_ips.pl < your_file
```

Loop over all files (with backup):

```
for f in /named_ext/*; do rename s/$/.bak/ $f; perl exchange_ips.pl < $f.bak > $f; done
```

---

*Example:*

Sample file to modifiy:

```
# some foo
subdomain                       A       200.201.202.203
# duplicate
subdomain                       A       200.201.202.203
# some bar
otherdomain                     A       99.99.99.99
otherdomain                     A       1.1.1.1
# another duplicate
subdomain                       A       200.201.202.203
```

Output of `exchange_const()`:

```
# some foo
subdomain                       A       123.123.123.123
subdomain                       A       124.124.124.124
subdomain                       A       125.125.125.125
# duplicate
# some bar
otherdomain                     A       99.99.99.99
otherdomain                     A       1.1.1.1
# another duplicate
```

Output of `exchange_incr()`:

```
# some foo
subdomain                       A       200.201.202.204
subdomain                       A       200.201.202.205
subdomain                       A       200.201.202.206
# duplicate
# some bar
otherdomain                     A       99.99.99.99
otherdomain                     A       1.1.1.1
# another duplicate
```

Comment: Great, but the looping is not working for me. Doesn't seem to be creating the bak files.

Comment: I see in some cases, the origin line is declared twice with same IP. Is there any way with regex to delete the second one to avoid duplicating the return and avoid getting 6 lines?

Comment: @Martin You can try changing `rename s/$/.bak/ $f;` to `mv $f $f.bak;` in the loop if `rename` doesn't work. Also, I edited my answer/script to filter duplicates by just remembering a found line and ignoring subsequent matches.

Answer (score 2):

### Small bash script

You can do this with a simple `sed` command over each file:

```
for f in ./named_ext/* ; do
    sed -r -i 's/subdomain[ ]+A[ ]+200.201.202.203/subdomain A 200.201.202.204\nsubdomain A 200.201.202.205\nsubdomain A 200.201.202.206/g' $f
done
```

---

### Explanation

The for loop enumerates `./named_ext/*` and runs the `sed` line using the file `$f`. The `-r` will extend the regular expressian and `-i` will edit the file in place.

The regular expression replaces

```
subdomain                    A       200.201.202.203
```

with any number of spaces by

```
subdomain A 200.201.202.204
subdomain A 200.201.202.205
subdomain A 200.201.202.206
```

If you want to retain spacing, you can add the spaces in the `sed` line.

Comment: +1 Finally a good solution with `sed`! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

tempFile=tempFile

for f in /named_ext/* ; do
    awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "."}

    /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ {
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            $4++
            print $0
        }
    }' $f > $tempFile
    mv $tempFile $f
done
```